If a class of binary relations is axiomatizable w/o equality, are their reflexive reductions also axiomatizable w/o equality?
This is a natural follow-up to this previous question, here: If a class of binary relations is first-order axiomatizable, are their reflexive reductions axiomatizable w/o equality?. My current question is, let $C$ be a class of binary relations such that $C$ is first-order-without-equality axiomatizable. Now, let $C'$ be the class of reflexive reductions of the binary relations in $C$, meaning those relations minus the identity relation. Is $C'$ a first-order-without-equality axiomatizable class of binary relations? Note, the example given in the answer to the previous question is no longer a counterexample of the current question, because the class of strict linear orders is not axiomatizable without equality.

No. Let $C$ be the class of linear (non-strict) preorders, i.e., relations $\leq$ that are,

Reflexive, i.e., $\forall x, x \leq x$;
Transitive, i.e., $\forall x \forall y \forall z, (x \leq y \wedge y \leq z) \Rightarrow x \leq z$;
Total, i.e., $\forall x \forall y, x \leq y \vee y \leq x$.

$C$ is first-order axiomatizable without equality. But the reflexive reductions, $C’$, is the class of linear strict preorders, which, for the same reason as the linked answer, is not first-order axiomatizable without equality: without equality, it is not possible to distinguish between the empty relation on sets $X$ of different sizes, but it is a linear strict preorder iff $X$ is a singleton.

While this is not that relevant, here is the precise definition of what I called linear strict preorders: a binary relation $<$ is called a linear strict preorder if it is,

Anti-reflexive, i.e., $\forall x, \neg x < x$;
Transitive modulo equality, i.e., $\forall x \forall y \forall z, (x < y \wedge y < z) \Rightarrow (x < z \vee x = z)$;
Total, i.e., $\forall x \forall y, x < y \vee x = y \vee y < x$.


Actually, I now realize, a simpler example would be the class of all total relations, that is, binary relations $R$ such that $(\forall x )(\forall y) xRy$. It is axiomatizable without equality, but its reflexive reductions are the class of inequality relations.

@user107952 Ah, true, that is an easier example. I was just following the example in the answer you linked to, so ended up with preorders.
